# PHP open tag "<?php" appears in the terminal/command line (Yii2 framework)

Tags: php, command-line, yii2

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 serve with Apache 2.4 and the newest Yii2 framework.
When I run any command in the terminal I see alaways the php open tag string `"<?php"` in the terminal/command line output:

```
$ php yii sync/added
<?phpSync - added videos
```

I have checked the source code but I do not see any `var_dump`, `echo` or `print` commands. Also `ob_start` and `ob_end` is removed.

Does somebody has any ide, why I see this `<?php` open tag in the command line?

Comment: be sure that the file you are working is a .php file.

Comment: Yes, they are php files.

Answer (score 0):

Check controller SyncController in folder "commands", if I right understand you

Comment: I do not see nothing with this php class. Really, If I run other command like Yii built-in command: `php yii migrate` the result will be: `<?phpYii Migration tool (based on Yii v2.0.11-dev)`

Comment: php yii migrade - it is default Yii commande.
php yii sync/added it is added or extentions
Run php yii to see all command

Comment: But what should I looking for? If I run that I see the `<?php` again and a new line where I can see the `This is Yii version...`